# logo in middle of navigation - how to vertically center

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I'm trying to create a header/nav bar where there will be navigation options on either side of a logo, which I would like all to be vertically centered. To achieve this, I'm using `<li>` and `<li class>` elements, but am having little luck with the vertical centering. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="btn"><a href="#"><span>01</span>Home</a></li>
            <li class="btn"><a href="#"><span>02</span>Vendors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="sews logo" /></a></li>
            <li class="btn"><a href="#"><span>03</span>Tickets</a></li>
            <li class="btn"><a href="#"><span>04</span>Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 600px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
    margin:0 10px;
}

nav ul li.btn a {
    padding-top: -10px;
}

nav ul li a span {
    color: #e3c22a;

font-family: fanwood;
```

}

Comment: You can try with margin-top:50%.

Comment: one of the most helpful pages on the internet: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: @EL I wish it was that easy; no luck :(

Comment: Any of these techniques helps you? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To vertically center something, apply the css rules `display: table cell` in addition to `vertical-align: middle` on the container element.

Comment: In what context? (does `vertical-align: middle` belong with .btn, or nav as a whole?)

Comment: it belongs on `nav`. It gets applied to the container element (see the article I referred you to in the comments)

Comment: Got it. I've implemented the edits you've recommended, but noticed no changes. Any ideas?
http://jsfiddle.net/6smrF/

Comment: you actually didn't implement the edits I recommended. I said to apply display: table-cell to the container element (`nav`), not the `li` elements. Leave them as inline. That should work (I'm having weird issues with jsfiddle so I'm having trouble testing)

Comment: Yup, that works: http://jsfiddle.net/6smrF/7/. Important note: I took out your padding on nav and added a height and a border to better illustrate that it works.

Comment: I've updated http://jsfiddle.net/6smrF/9/ to show what I'm seeing; all content is still aligned on bottom and shifted to the left.

Comment: so what was occurring there was that it was sizing all of the lis to the same as the one with the image, but not aligning the text inside those (remove the display and alignment from the lis that I just added to the fiddle I'm about to link to and you'll see what I mean). To have everything centered, you want to apply the display and alignment properties to nav and the lis (see http://jsfiddle.net/6smrF/17/)

Answer (score 0):

If the links and image were in the same element, say a div, you could set the image to use the style tag: vertical-align: middle;

Answer (score -1):

`position relative` the header. `position absolute` the image. `left: 50%;` the image

Comment: vertically centered, not horizontally.